# Topnav is not touching the top of the HTML

Tags: html

I was making an HTML file from scratch and the `.topnav` did not reach the top of the website.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
div {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Audiowide';font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide' rel='stylesheet'>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="">Sup</a>
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href=""></a>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I make it reach the top of the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for margin on the body.

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```css
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
}

body {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
div {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Audiowide';font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide' rel='stylesheet'>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="">Sup</a>
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href=""></a>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I will accept your answer when it lets me because it says "You cannot accept answers in 10 minutes".